# Change background image javascript and position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple question. I created a code. The background changes in the given time value. However, poorly positioned. I want to give him an ID to position the background in CSS. How can I do this?

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #clock {
      text-align: center;
    position: relative;
      top: 50%;
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px;

     }

    #image-head {
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="clock">12:13:14</div>
    <div id="image-head" class="image-head"></div>
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E52_-e1NXV86qUJ9t5mcvi59nkhuKIruz--9IgULez8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's unclear what you are trying to do. Include all code in the question, no links.

Comment: The full code is available at the link, it will be dropped by me if I try to insert it.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Here would be the [DEMO page](https://jsbin.com/rigasuzaxi/edit?html,css,js,output) The background is changing. But without any parameters. For example, I want to make it appear in the current "#image-head" location. How can I get CCS to set where images should appear?